# How to use angular universal with asp.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am a new to angular universal but I used angular+asp.net core for few projects.

Can any one guide me how to use angular universal with asp.net core 2.1?.

How to run asp.net core project to run angular for server side rendering (SSR)?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 is no longer supported. [Here's a walkthrough](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-update-705c0ec01931) for .NET Core 3.1, and [here's a walkthrough](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976) for .NET 6

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can we use .Net core 2.1 for angular universal?. Because I have installed visual studio 2017

Comment: What's wrong with using Visual Studio 2022? [But sure you can](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/2.1/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L32) Why would you start off with a new project with an already deprecated SDK?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I installed VS 2022 and I followed your article https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976    . But There is an issue on below code line. services.AddSpaPrerenderingService<Services.SpaPrerenderingService>(); It says "The type or namespace name 'Services' could not be found". Can you kindly let me know the way to sort it out?

Comment: That's whatever you named your `IServiceCollection` [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/Demo/Demo.Web/Startup.cs#L28)

Comment: The extension method is declared [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/SpaRouteExtensions.cs#L11), so make sure you have the following using in the Startup.cs or Program.cs: `using MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing`. ctrl ; would suggest this for you also

Comment: I am able to follow the steps successfully. But after run the project, I received below error. "NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Test1\Test1\ClientApp\dist\ClientApp\server\main.js' ". What may be the reason for the issue?

Comment: Well, when your angular app is hosted through your asp.net core app, the server bootmodule will be produced at `ClientApp/dist/server/main.js`. In your case, since the angular app is not inside the asp.net core app's folder, this path will be different.

Comment: So my suggestion is to copy over the server/main.js to somewhere in your asp.net core app, include it as an asset, and point to this file

Comment: Thank you. Suppose that I have a working angular project. How can I convert it to work as server side rendering?

Comment: Can you update SSR Angular 14 with .NET Core 7?
I just download source code in this link https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976 but not working. it error @Pieterjan

Comment: "Is not working" is very vague. Can you check the VS Output window for errors and post them here (or create a new SO question and post the link here)? I also created a [dotnet template here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates#updating-the-installed-template-packages), but run `npm i` from the `ClientApp` folder in a non-elevated cmd.